# Displaying a portlet only when user is logged in

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have a requirement to display a specific portlet only if the user is logged in. 
My question is what would be the appropriate way to handle this kind of requirement. Should I handle it through code by using

> renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATOR_VISIBILITY, Boolean.FALSE);

Or is this kind of configuration done using portlet's roles or any kind of portal properties?

As per my understanding, this might be handled by adding a role to the portlet, but I am not sure about where and how to set portlet roles.

Comment: You can simply remove VIEW permission for Portet for GUEST Role from Portlet Configuration > Permission

Comment: I did it, but when user is not logged in, I am getting error message like you don't have permission to access this portlet.

Comment: There is one portal property `layout.show.portlet.access.denied=true` available to not show such message. override it with value false then it will not show that error message.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, I got to know this can be handled on portlet level as well. we have to set some tag in portlet.xml or some file I am not sure. Do you have any idea how to avoid such message on portlet mode.

Comment: Yes, you can define init parameter named as `show-portlet-access-denied` in portlet's portlet.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply remove VIEW permission for Portlet for GUEST Role from Portlet Configuration -> Permissions tab.

By this, GUEST user will see error message like : You do not have permission to access this portlet.

If you want to avoid this message you can override portal property `layout.show.portlet.access.denied` to value false. This will apply to portal level for each portlet.

If you want to hide permission error message specific to portlet, then in portlet.xml  you can define init parameter `show-portlet-access-denied` with value as false.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, Are you talking about something like this <init-param>
   <name>show-portlet-access-denied</name>
   <value>false</value>
   </init-param> In portlet.xml

Comment: well, in my case setting init param in portlet.xml did not worked. i dont know if I have written wrong syntax, but yes setting  'layout.show.portlet.access.denied' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific Portlet put the property in the `liferay-portlet.xml` under the tag `<icon>`

```
<show-portlet-access-denied>false</show-portlet-access-denied>
```